# unable to display contact data image in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

i am trying to fetch the contact profile pic i.e. avatar of contact data using following code in `PhoneGap` for `android`
but i am getting following url in return and i don't know how should i show it in a `img` tag.

Code

```
  var defaultImagePath ='../resources/images/default_usr.png'

 var img = contacts[i].photos  != null ? 
     contacts[i].photos[0].value : defaultImagePath;
```

returned url is

> content://com.android.contacts/contacts/739/photo

now when eventually in a list i am trying to show it using

```
<img src="content://com.android.contacts/contacts/739/photo"/>
```

but its not displaying anything ? so how would i show the contact image ?

i have the latest `PhoneGap` version

i have used

> window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI( contacts[i].photos[0].value , this.onResolveSuccess, this.fail);

but i am getting following run time error

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference in phonegap
```

even though i have specified following permissions in android

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
```

**UPDATE**

```
loadContacts:function(){



    var arr = [];

    var filter = ["displayName", "name", "phoneNumbers","emails","addresses","photos"];
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter=""; 
    options.multiple=true;    

    navigator.contacts.find(filter,
              function(contacts) {

                for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                  if (contacts[i].photos) {


                     for (var j = 0; j < contacts[i].photos.length; j++) {



                                returnValidPhoto(contacts[i].photos[j], function(answer) {

                                        console.log(answer);

                                        if(contacts[i].photos[j]!=null);
                                         contacts[i].photos[j].value=answer;


                                    });




                                 var contactData = new ContactData("Name" ,
                                                    "09090909",
                                                     contacts[i].photos[j].value);

                                arr.push(contactData);




                  }
                }

            }
            Ext.getStore('ContactStore').setData(arr);

               // document.getElementById("contactdata").innerHTML = data; 
            }, function(err) {
                alert(err);
              },options);



    }
```

here is the image function

```
 function returnValidPhoto(url,callback){

    console.log("IMAGE CALLED");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
    //Image is ok

        console.log("IMAGE OK");

        callback(url.value);
    };
    img.onerror = function(err) {
        //Returning a default image for users without photo 

                console.log("IMAGE FAILED");

        url.value = "/resources/images/default_usr.png";
        callback("/resources/images/default_usr.png");
    }
    img.src = url.value;
};
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem, contact imge is not showing...

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
     function onDeviceReady() {
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("content://com.android.contacts/contacts/739/photo", onResolveSuccess, fail);
        }

        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            console.log(fileSystem.name);
        }

        function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {
            console.log(fileEntry.name);
        }

        function fail(evt) {
            console.log(evt.target.error.code);
        }
```

Comment: i am getting following error if i use above code 

`JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference in phonegap` and app stops, see my edits

Comment: hi do you add  <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> permission

Comment: and also debuggable="true" in AndoidMainfeast.xml

Comment: yeah i permission is already there and i tried after setting `debuggable` but same result , have you tried it at your end ?

Comment: do you use 3.0.0 version

Comment: `i have phonegap 2.9.0`

Comment: Do set this all permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

Comment: Yeah , i have specified all the permission its been written in my question

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue a few days ago and finally found a workaround.

```
var returnValidPhoto=function(url,callback){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
    //Image is ok
        callback(url);
    };
    img.onerror = function(err) {
        //Returning a default image for users without photo 
        callback("image_for_no_avatar.png");
    }
    img.src = url;
};

//Example usage
returnValidphoto(contact.photos[0].value, function(answer) {
    contact.photos[0].value=answer;
}
```

Comment: when i set `contact.photos[0].value=answer;`  i am getting error `cant read property 'photos' of undefined`

Comment: You should check if it is defined too, most of contacts in phonegap have photos=null.

Comment: as for me, i am building a new array of "validContacts" after doing navigator.contacts.find and filtering all those without phone numbers or names and settings defaults photos

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for me. I didn't use a callback, but instead passed the contact (user model) into the function, and on error I update the model's picture attribute to the default one. Then in my view where I have already rendered this user, I listen for changes on the picture attribute and re-render.

Answer (score 0):

beside AndroidManifest.xml, there are permission of phonegap at `project\res\xml\config.xml`

```
 <plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    ...
  </plugins>
```

please check that also if all permission are granted for the JNI ERROR, that error can be permission error.

For the image, `<img src="content://com.android.contacts/contacts/739/photo"/>` make sure that contact id 739 has image setup since phonegap get_contact function always return a url format like `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/XXX/photo` where XXX is contact id, no matter what image is set or not.

As I test with phonegap 2.5 on android 4, `<img src="content://com.android.contacts/contacts/739/photo"/>` is work, contact image or a small-blue-square-with-question-mark-inside in case that uri does not contain image

Comment: ya its working now , but i got the issue of distinguish between null and image and for that plugin is the only option ?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know.